# Cluster 3d data using color information - Python

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means, open3d

My point cloud consists of XYZ values and for each xyz there is corresponding color (RGB) value.  I don't have any other information in my data eg:intensity, classification etc., as this point cloud was derived from images not from lidar.

My idea was to extract features( lanes detection) using rgb data. I found so much from the google but all are using intensity values from the lidar,unfortunately i can't.

What I have done:1)read pcd
2)Apply grid
3)perform Ransac(not showed in the code here)

```
def voxelAvgColor(eachvoxel) : 
  colorinfo = sum(clrs[eachvoxel])/(len(clrs[eachv oxel]))
  return colorinfo

pointcloud = lp.read(”data_01_2021.las”)
points = np.vstack((pointcloud.x, pointcloud.y,pointcloud.z)).transpose()
colors = np.vstack((pointcloud.red, pointcloud.green,pointcloud.blue)).transpose()

pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud() pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(colors/65535) 
rgb = np.asarray(pcd.colors)
xyz = np.asarray(pcd.points) 

o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([pcd])

voxelgrid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.createfrompointcloud(pcd, voxelsize = 0.40)
print(”voxelplottingstarted........”)

o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([voxelgrid])
voxels = voxelgrid.getvoxels()
indices = np.stack(list(vx.gridindex for vx in voxels))
clrs = np.stack(list(vx.color for vx in voxels))
GridPcd =o3d.geometry. PointCloud()
GrodPcd.points=o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(indices)
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(clrs)
 o3d.visualization.drawgeometries([GridPcd])
```

4. now to detect the lanes, i want to Cluster the inlier points.

My questions:
Which clustering is best for my next step. I thought of dbscan and I applied but i can't able to extract the lanes. So, I am looking for other algorithm that clusters the data using my color information of the point cloud and form clusters based on the color data(since lanes are white it should form cluster on lane markings and road are black and it should form another cluster, some thing like this)

edit: I also tried K means but couldn't extract white lanes.

Comment: Anyone, please give me some Ideas how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
from math import sqrt
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans 
import pandas_datareader as dr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import seaborn as sn

start = '2019-1-1'
end = '2020-1-1'

tickers = ['AXP','AAPL','BA','CAT','CSCO','CVX','XOM','GS','HD','IBM','INTC','JNJ','KO','JPM','MCD',    'MMM',  'MRK',  'MSFT', 'NKE','PFE','PG','TRV','UNH','RTX','VZ','V','WBA','WMT','DIS','DOW']
prices_list = []
for ticker in tickers:
    try:
        prices = dr.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start)['Adj Close']
        prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
        prices.columns = [ticker]
        prices_list.append(prices)
    except:
        pass
    prices_df = pd.concat(prices_list,axis=1)
prices_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
prices_df.head()


# 3D Plot of KMeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
km.fit(X)
km.predict(X)
labels = km.labels_#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(7,7))
ax = Axes3D(fig, rect=[0, 0, 0.95, 1], elev=48, azim=134)
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], 
          c=labels.astype(np.float), edgecolor="k", s=50)
ax.set_xlabel("X-axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y-axis")
ax.set_zlabel("Z-axis")
plt.title("K Means", fontsize=14)
```

Result.

[image]

All details here.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20-%20Historical%20Stock%20Prices.ipynb